# Integer-overflow on array index

Tags: c, integer-overflow

I use C on an 32-bit architecture.

If I use `array[-2147483635]` why does C translate it to `array[13]`?

`-2147483635` on Two’s Complement is `10000000000000000000000000001101b`

Does it take the left bit and translate it to 0 so that it becomes
`00000000000000000000000000001101b`, that is `13`???

I don't think that it is cast to `size_t`. Because `size_t` translates `-2147483635` to `4294967264`.

Comment: Why do you think it translates `to array[13]`?

Comment: i see witch address it write there

Comment: what is the type of `array`?

Comment: @jordan Please show the code that demonstrates your assertion.

Comment: @jordan `int array[10]; that` ??? What ?

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't translate to `array[13]`, but properly to `array[-2147483635]`. However, this might still cause undefined behaviour. For example, on 32-bit x86, the assembly for

```
char f(char * a) { return a[-2147483635]; }
int g(int * a) { return a[-2147483635]; }
```

might look like:

```
f:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movzbl  -2147483635(%eax), %eax
    popl    %ebp
    ret
g:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movl    52(%eax), %eax
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

See online example [here](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g6,options:'-xc+-m32',source:'char+f(char+*+a)+%7B%0A++++return+a%5B-2147483635%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+g(int+*+a)+%7B%0A++++return+a%5B-2147483635%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3). So all looks good for the `char` array, but you can see the overflow for the integer array (`movl 52(%eax), %eax` where 52 is 4×13). This is caused by the undefined behaviour, because on 32-bit systems, the element with index -2147483635 **can not possibly exist** for any array or pointer. For arrays, it *would* point to some element before the first element of the array, hence undefined behaviour. For any pointer, if you only have a maximum of 2<sup>32</sup> or 4294967296 bytes of memory, and lets say that `array` points to the last byte at index 2<sup>32</sup>-1 or 4294967295, then the -2147483635-th element would have to reside at memory address `4294967295 + ((-2147483635)*sizeof(int))` which is `4294967295 - 8589934540` which is `-4294967245`. Such a memory address does not make sense.

See [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Pointer_arithmetic) or the C standard at §6.5.6(8) for details.

Comment: so i can't know wicth type the minus save ? if it size_t or unsigned int?
and why did i get integer overflow? because i put minus on index? so it must translate to plus?

Comment: @jordan I extensively improved my answer with respect to your comments to the question

Answer (score 3):

`-2147483635` fits well within the range of a 4-byte signed integer, since the lower limit is `–2147483648`.

Subscripting arrays with negative indexes is undefined behaviour because it involves accessing memory that is out of its bounds. Only if `array` is in fact a pointer and points beyond the `2147483635 * sizeof(int)` byte of a large-enough contiguously-allocated region of memory, you may use this negative index.

Comment: so why it become 13?
because undefined behaviour?
it correct to tell that the left bit become 0?

Comment: @jordan: Post the exact code that you are compiling. Besides, how can you be certain that the index evaluates to `13`?

Comment: i sure that 13 becuase i see the pleace it write there
is it impassable that it takes to left bit and put 0 there?